# Dynamically re-order numbered list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, is there a way to dynamically update the priority for a list of tasks? For example, if you have a column with priorities 1, 5, 3, 2, 4 and a user added a new row with a new task and assigns it a priority of 1, the list is updated with 2, 6, 4, 3, 5, 1?

Or is there some other (better?) way of doing this? I'd rather not have to sort the list and then manually change the numbering every time a new task is added or removed. Plus, I don't think the people who will use the spreadsheet will do that.

Comment: Why not just do a sorted list, then add in the extra row at the desired location and put your new task in there? ... It eliminates the need for numbering altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngPriorityList As Range
Dim lNewValue As Long
Dim myCell As Range

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then 'Only run if the a number was entered

        Set rngPriorityList = ThisWorkbook.Names("priority").RefersToRange 'the named range for the task list

        If Not Intersect(Target, rngPriorityList) Is Nothing Then 'Only run the following in the cell being updated was in the priority list range
            For Each myCell In rngPriorityList.Cells 'Loop through the priority list range
                If myCell.Value = Target.Value _
                And myCell.Address <> Target.Address Then 'Finding cells with the same value, excluding the cell being changes
                    myCell.Value = myCell.Value + 1 'Increment the prioriry by 1
                End If
            Next myCell
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It does work, but after testing it on a small list (only 6 items), the value updates and then Excel hangs for several seconds before I can do anything. Is that normal?

Comment: Have you added it to the vba code for the worksheet that stores your task list? Have you updated it to get the correct range for rngPriorityList?

Comment: On even longer lists (such as up to 30), it hangs Excel and goes to Not Responding for nearly a minute. Not sure if it's something in the code or something on my end. I've never had Excel hang before.

Comment: It was me. I had given the column a name (priority) so it was going through the whole length of the column even when it was blank.

Comment: On another side note, if I delete a priority value and make it zero (0), the script automatically numbers everything. I'm not good enough with VBA to troubleshoot that issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: TW_Doc (any anybody that sees in the future, which is how I stumbled upon it), I added this bit of code after the "If Not Intersect" line: "If Target.Value >= 1 Then". The corresponding "End If" came after the "Next myCell" line.

Answer (score 1):

I would lean towards a VBA answer but I found formulas and addition of columns to do what you need without macros. *See image below*

To keep this working from one addition to the next, after each new task is added you would have to copy your sorted task list in columns E:F, paste the values in A3, and delete the values in B2 and C2. Then you would need to drag your formulas down at the bottom of columns C:F since your list just got longer.

This is the biggest problem I can see doing it with in cell formulas, updating requires copy paste delete.

[image: Dynamically Change a numbered list based on a Set Priority Formulas]
[image: Dynamically Change a numbered list based on a Set Priority Results]

Comment: I figured it could be done in cells with formulas, but the copying is something I'd like to avoid. The people using this won't do all those steps and would't follow directions for it. They want to type into, save it, and be done. (Spoiled!)

Comment: @scheballs +1 for this alternative approach - generally better practice to solve xl problems using built in functionality rather than `vba`